# Can someone who uses their action to break free from the Rime's Binding Ice spell's ice formations use their movement on that very same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, action-economy

Someone who fails the save for [Rime's Binding Ice](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/rimes-binding-ice) is "hindered by ice formations for 1 minute, or until it or another creature within reach of it uses an action to break away the ice. A creature hindered by ice has its speed reduced to 0."

Most spells that reduce your movement will hold you in place for at least one round, even if you save at the first opportunity after your initial failure.  (For example, [Hold Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hold-person) allows a new save at the end of your turn, so even if you save your chance to move during that first turn is gone.)  However, as written, Rime's Binding Ice appears to only cost your first action and not your movement.

This seems awfully weak, even for a spell that's only second level.  Have I misunderstood the mechanics?

Comment: As someone using an app for spells and my app version missed out the ability to free yourself I thought this was a super useful spell, but being able to free yourself entirely sucks the wind out of this spell for me now I have checked the proper version! Boo. Hiss.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, they can break free and move on their next turn

Here’s the full description of the [*rime's binding ice*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/rimes-binding-ice) spell (FToD, p. 21; emphasis mine):

> A burst of cold energy emanates from you in a **30-foot cone**. Each creature in that area must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, a creature **takes 3d8 cold damage and is hindered by ice formations for 1 minute, or until it or another creature within reach of it uses an action to break away the ice**. A creature hindered by ice has its speed reduced to 0. On a successful save, a creature takes half as much damage and isn’t hindered by ice.

The spell does not say the creature saves at the end of the turn, the save is made immediately, and if failed, the creature is stuck until it or another creature uses its action to break free. The creature is not incapacitated, so it can use its action on its very next turn to break free, and then move normally that same turn.

My impression is that what’s throwing you off is not the wording, which is quite clear and which you interpret correctly, but that you think the effect is far too weak.

That’s just not the case. The spell is not weak for a 2nd-level spell.

First, it is an **area effect**, so, unlike *hold person*, it can immediately affect multiple creatures that fail the save. Being able to negate the actions of multiple creatures for one action of yours is a strong effect, action-economy wise.

Second, and as important, it is an **area-damage spell**, on par with the 2nd-level area-damage spell *shatter*, which also deals 3d8 damage (in that case, thunder damage in a 10-foot radius, expected to only hit about half the number of targets compared to this, but easier to place). Shatter is a good spell, able to kill many low-level opponents such as goblins. So can this. The freezing comes on top of this, and gives you a valuable effect against tougher opponents, where negating one attack routine has a lot of impact.

Comment: Right rule interpretation, but I really disagree that the freezing is the icing on the cake, the control effect is far more important than the damage. You don't fight goblins all the time, and when you do, you don't need to waste precious spells. The control effect makes this useful against more powerful creatures, the damage doesn't.

Comment: @SeriousBri: There certainly is no objective way to say any aspect of the spell is more important than another. And against tougher opponents, the freeze may indeed be more important. I meant it’s added on top of an otherwise comparable effect (damage) that we have a core reference spell for. And, honestly, I just could not resist the pun.

Comment: @SeriousBri, I edited see if you like this better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Groody.  I was looking for a level 1 or 2 "elemental" type spell that could keep enemies from moving (or at least slow them down), so from that perspective this spell seemed weak -- but I see what you mean about the usefulness of stealing the actions from several creatures.  Unfortunately, that wasn't what I needed for my purposes.  At this point, my best option may be to just reflavor the Grease spell as ice.

Comment: @gto That sounds like an excellent solution for a reflavor!